# How can I get the link to my app with the latest update available?

Tags: android, google-play

I know there is this method:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package_name

But I have tried this method, when you launch this link, google play opens and you can see the application BUT it only shows you the options "Uninstall" and "Open", there is no "Update" version.

To fix this you need to launch play store then search for the app, only then you are able to see the "Update" option.

Is there any way to fix this? I have seen many apps give you a dialog and when you press it they send you to the update page directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's in app update library

Comment: I am currently using Flutter and this method seems very confusing to implement and debug. You can't debug unless the current app version is from the play store, so u need to make workarounds (making alpha or beta apps), it just does not seem beginner friendly. I would prefer a manual method to detect the version and just open the market when it detects version does not match or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

if you want open playmarket to update app

try this:

```
    String PackageName = MainActivity.getPackageName();
    MainActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + PackageName)));
```

Comment: I know this is not to be asked in here since I did not specify... is it possible to do this with Flutter?

Comment: ok it seems possible with this package https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus I will try